# Update Elasticsearch Doc field with Array Type

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I have a document in the form of:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/books/book/1 -d '{
    "user_id": 1,
    "pages": [ {"page_id": 1, "count": 1}, {"page_id": 2, "count": 3}]
}
```

Now lets say the user reads page 1 again, so I want to increment the count. The document should become:

```
{
   "user_id": 1,
   "pages": [ {"page_id": 1, "count": 2}, {"page_id": 2, "count": 3}]
}
```

But how do you do this update of an element of a list using an if variable?

An example of a simple update in Elasticsearch is as follows:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/books/book/2 -d '{
   "user_id": 1,
   "pages": { 
   "page_1": 1,
   "page_2": 2
   }
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/books/book/2/_update -d '
{ 
    "script": "ctx._source.pages.page_1+=1"
}'
```

The document now becomes:

```
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "pages": { 
      "page_1": 1,
      "page_2": 2
}
```

However this more simple format of a doc looses stating the page_id as a field, so the id itself acts as the field. Similarly the value associated to the field has no real definition. Thus this isn't a great solution.

Anyway, would be great to have any ideas on how to update the array accordingly or any ideas on structuring of the data.

Note: Using ES 1.4.4, You also need to add `script.disable_dynamic: false` to your `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your problem correctly, I would probably use a [parent/child](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) relationship.

To test it, I set up an index with a `"user"` parent and `"page"` child, as follows:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "_id": {
            "path": "user_id"
         },
         "properties": {
            "user_id": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      },
      "page": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "user"
         },
         "_id": {
            "path": "page_id"
         },
         "properties": {
            "page_id": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "count": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

(I used the `"path"` parameter in the `"_id"`s because it makes the indexing less redundant; the ES docs say that [`path`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html#_path) is deprecated in ES 1.5, but they don't say what it's being replaced with.)

Then indexed a few docs:

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":1}
{"index":{"_type":"page","_parent":1}}
{"page_id":1,"count":1}
{"index":{"_type":"page","_parent":1}}
{"page_id":2,"count":1}
```

Now I can use a [scripted partial update](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates) to increment the `"count"` field of a `page`. Because of the parent/child relationship, I have to use the `parent` [parameter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-update.html#_parameters_3) to tell ES how to route the request.

```
POST /test_index/page/2/_update?parent=1
{
   "script": "ctx._source.count+=1"
}
```

Now if I search for that document, I will see that it was updated as expected:

```
POST /test_index/page/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "page_id": {
              "value": "2"
           }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "page",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "page_id": 2,
               "count": 2
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code all in one place:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/9c977f15b514ec251aef8e84e9510d3de43aef8a